# Refactor AngularJS Unique Form Field Directive to be Non-Blocking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using this AngularJS 1.2 directive to check on whether a form field is unique by making an $http request with the model data, and checking the response.

But, when it is processing the request it blocks any other subsequent requests, and it will also register a success for that prior request when currently the model is not unique.

I'm not sure how correct this other than by checking for uniqueness on blur of the form field, which isn't quite the interaction I was hoping to achieve.  Any suggestions for refactoring this?

```
.directive('unique', ['$http', '$timeout', 
    function( $http, $timeout ) {

        var processing = null;

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=ngModel',
                unique: '&'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl ) {

                // Watch change to model
                $scope.$watch(function() {

                    return $scope.ngModel;

                }, function( currentValue ) {

                    // Debounce before checking unique
                    if ( !processing && angular.isDefined( $scope.ngModel ) ) {
                        processing = $timeout(function() {

                            $scope.unique( { name: $attrs.name } )

                                .then(function( response ) {

                                    // Set model validity based on result, allows use of $error.unique
                                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('unique', response.data.isUnique);
                                    processing = null;
                                }, function( error ) {

                                    // Set model validity based on result, allows use of $error.unique
                                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('unique', false);
                                    processing = null;
                                });

                        }, 500);
                    }
                });

                $scope.$on( "$destroy", function( event ) {
                    $timeout.cancel( processing );
                });
            }
        };
}]);
```

Comment: can you use 1.3 or 1.4? AngularJS improved support for async form validators through ngModel and its controller.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but try moving "var processing = null;" to inside your link function, otherwise it will be common to all instances of your directive. Even if that isn't causing your issue, I can see it causing others down the line.

Comment: Hi @pixelbits, it's actually the end of a 9 month project and this is the final bug fix, otherwise I'd definitely try to update.

Comment: Does unique throw an error if its not unique? or does the method return true/false? If it is the latter, I suspect you're not handling the response properly

Comment: Hi @FoxMulder900, yah that wouldn't solve my issue, but thanks that is a very good point.  I've just made that update.

Comment: Hi @pixelbits, the latency of the response is the issue coupled with processing blocking further requests until the current request's response is received.  The validity of the model is set preventing the form from being submitted, and when it is invalid a error message is displayed noting the field fails validation.